# array of values from acf repeater into cf7 dropdown

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I'm trying to populate a cf7 dropdown with values from an acf repeater. If I use a regular hardcoded array, it works just fine so somehow I'm messing up when getting the values of the repeater field.

Here's what I've got rn, trying to push the values into an array:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args) {
  if (in_array('gigs', $options)){

$gigs = array();
if( have_rows('termine') ):
        while ( have_rows('termine') ) : the_row();
               $gigs[] = get_sub_field('termin');
        endwhile;
endif;
return $gigs;
        
  }
  return $n;

}, 10, 3);
```

tried moving the return statement around a bit but that didn't help either and I am at a loss with my barely existing php knowledge.

Any ideas or pointers where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to return `$n` which is either null or a value which would be an array.  You are close, but your returning the wrong thing. A good example of how to use this filter is by looking at the code from [listo.php](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/master/modules/listo.php) an you can see the correct usage of this filter.

With that said... without testing your ACF values, I can't say if your function will return those... but the below function is tested and will return data to your select with `data:gigs` if the ACF function works.

To retrieve the containing post's `post_id` you need to dig into the unit tag, and get the page id.  The global `$post` won't work inside this filter, as it's not passing any of the loop properties to the function, so you have to specify your ACF field with the second parameter - which needs to be the parent post id.

```php
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', 'dd_filter_form_tag_data', 10, 3 );
function dd_filter_form_tag_data( $n, $options, $args ) {
    // Get the current form.
    $cf7 = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();
    // Get the form unit tag.
    $unit_tag = $cf7->unit_tag();
    // Turn the string into an array.
    $tag_array = explode( '-', $unit_tag );
    // The 3rd item in the array will be the page id.
    $post_id = substr( $tag_array[2], 1 );

    if ( in_array( 'gigs', $options, true ) ) {
        $gigs = array();
        if ( have_rows( 'termine', $post_id ) ) :
            while ( have_rows( 'termine', $post_id ) ) :
                the_row();
                $gigs[] = get_sub_field( 'termin' );
            endwhile;
        endif;
        $n = array_merge( (array) $n, $gigs );
    }
    return $n;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Not working yet though so I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I'm getting the acf values. Will try and investigate those a bit more

Comment: Let me ask you this, where are you storing the ACF values are they in an option or in a post?

Comment: In a post and the cf7 form is added to the individual post via shortcode inside the post loop so that in theory it should be getting that posts values, at least thats what I thought

Comment: Specify the post id. The post object won't be passed to the cf7 function

Comment: Makes sense why it hasn't been working then:) You mean to pass the post id inside the function correct?

Comment: You have to include the post_id in have_rows as ft second parameter. I can help in about 2 hours. On my phone now

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Will try n play around with it till then and see :)

Comment: Tried adding post->ID and other variations as second paramenter but the furthest I got was "Array" being an option in the dropdown

Comment: I've updated the answer which shows how to get the container post ID from the current contact form.

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately I'm using a postloop to show all posts on the same page so the page id stays the same :/ I guess I have to find a different way or just make a custom form maybe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243824/discussion-between-howard-e-and-martin-conde).