# Pass dynamic post id to cf7 form

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/tangible-loops-and-logic/ to show a list of posts. Each post also contains a Contact Form 7 form. That form has a dropdown which should be populated by an acf repeater field that is attached to each post.

My issue is that in order to retrieve the correct values I need to get the correct post id for each post. I know I can create a dynamic field in cf7 to show the post ID but I'm not really sure how I can pass that around so that I can retrieve the correct repeater.

My loop (simplified):

```
<Loop type=seminar count=3>
  <Field title />
  <div class="seminarContent">
    ...
  </div>
  [contact-form-7 id="619" title="Seminar"]
</Loop>
```

The select field of my form:

```
[select termine data:gigs]
```

my current code to retrieve the post ID which would work if it was on the single post page, but unfortunately not within a loop showing all posts on the same page as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71840727/6118046:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', 'dd_filter_form_tag_data', 10, 3 );
function dd_filter_form_tag_data( $n, $options, $args ) {
    // Get the current form.
    $cf7 = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();
    // Get the form unit tag.
    $unit_tag = $cf7->unit_tag();
    // Turn the string into an array.
    $tag_array = explode( '-', $unit_tag );
    // The 3rd item in the array will be the page id.
    $post_id = substr( $tag_array[2], 1 );

    if ( in_array( 'gigs', $options, true ) ) {
        $gigs = array();
        if ( have_rows( 'termine', $post_id ) ) :
            while ( have_rows( 'termine', $post_id ) ) :
                the_row();
                $gigs[] = get_sub_field( 'termin' );
            endwhile;
        endif;
        $n = array_merge( (array) $n, $gigs );
    }
    return $n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work if I use the previous version of the plugin, called "custom content shortcode". Then add a custom field (text) to my post in which I paste the cf7 shortcode (same for all posts) and then call the field in the frontend. Dropdown gets properly filled that way.